# Именам оканчиваются на 'Я' или 'А' дать значение 0

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я не правильно делаю? Необходимо именам которые оканчиваются на 'Я или А' дать значение 0

```js
let nameArr = ['Игорь', 'Яна', 'Валерий', 'Оля', 'Вячеслав', 'Борис']
let isMaleName = (name) => name.endsWith('а' || 'я') ? 1 : 0;
let numberArr = nameArr.map(isMaleName)

console.log(numberArr)
```

Comment: в вашем коде только один нюанс: 'а' || 'я' в методе endsWidth вернёт 'a' и будёт проверять заканчивается ли слово на 'a', но не будёт проверять на 'я'

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте вот так. Функция endsWith проверяет оканчивается ли на нужное вам значение строка и принимает один параметр. Поэтому вам нужно запускать две проверки через условие ИЛИ

```js
let nameArr = ['Игорь', 'Яна', 'Валерий', 'Оля', 'Вячеслав', 'Борис']

let isMaleName = (name) => name.endsWith('а') || name.endsWith('я') ? 1 : 0

let numberArr = nameArr.map(isMaleName)

console.log(numberArr)
```

Comment: отличное решение, только переменную тогда назвать isFemaleName

Comment: @АлексейОбухов лучше ещё упомянуть то, что на "я" и "а" оканчиваются всё же мужские имена тоже

Comment: согласен, тут надо провести более серьезный лингвистический анализ. тогда имя переменной можно оставить как есть )

Comment: Не знаю как тут оставлять благодарность)

Comment: А какие мужские имена оканчиваются на а или я?)

Comment: @ИгорьТрубников навскидку: Никита, Данила, Фома, Гаврила, Илья, Добрыня.......и это исконно русские. А если брать вообще - то можно открывать поисковик и смотреть)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let nameArr = ['Игорь', 'Яна', 'Валерий', 'Оля', 'Вячеслав', 'Борис'];
let newArr = [];
let arr = nameArr.map( item => item.slice(item.length-1))

for(let key of arr){
  if( key == 'а' || key == 'я' ){
    newArr.push(0)
  } else {
    newArr.push(1)
  }
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей задачи вполне хватит небольшой "регулярки":

```js
let nameArr = ['Игорь', 'Яна', 'Валерий', 'Оля', 'Вячеслав', 'Борис'];
let isMaleName = (name) => name.match(/[ая]$/i) ? 0 : 1;
let numberArr = nameArr.map(isMaleName);

console.log(numberArr);
```